# SqlDependency OnChangeEventHandler not firing when query changed inSqlCommand

Tags: c#, signalr, sqlcommand, sqldependency

I have written code using SqlDependency. In using select statement with list of columns, OnChangeEventHandler event is fired but when I change select statement to get count of rows, OnChangeEventHandler event does not fires up.

Code in which OnChangeEventHandler event fires:

public static class Notification
{
        static readonly string connString = @"data source=DESKTOP-591MN5Q\SQLEXPRESS01;initial catalog=New;integrated security=True;";
        internal static SqlCommand command = null;
        internal static SqlDependency dependency = null;

```
    public static int GetNotificationCount()
    {
        try
        {               
            var messages = new List<tblNotification>(); 
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  [NotificationId],[UserId],[IsSeen],[Message],[CreatedDate],[ActionID] FROM [dbo].[tblNotification]", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    if (dependency == null)
                    {
                        dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    }

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        messages.Add(item: new tblNotification
                        {
                            NotificationId = (int)reader["NotificationId"],
                            UserId = reader["UserId"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["UserId"] : "",
                            IsSeen = reader["IsSeen"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["IsSeen"] : "",
                            Message = reader["Message"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["Message"] : "",
                            CreatedDate = reader["CreatedDate"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["CreatedDate"] : "",
                            ActionID = reader["ActionID"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["ActionID"] : "",
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return messages.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dependency != null)
        {
            dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
            dependency = null;
        }
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            MyHub.Send();
        }
    }
}
```

Code in which OnChangeEventHandler event does not fires:

public static class Notification
{
    static readonly string connString = @"data source=DESKTOP-591MN5Q\SQLEXPRESS01;initial catalog=New;integrated security=True;";
    internal static SqlCommand command = null;
    internal static SqlDependency dependency = null;

```
public static int GetNotificationCount()
{
    try
    { 
        int notificationCt;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  COUNT([NotificationId]) as NotificationCount FROM [dbo].[tblNotification]", connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                if (dependency == null)
                {
                    dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                }

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                notificationCt = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar()); 
            }
        }
        return notificationCt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return 0;
    }
}

private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    if (dependency != null)
    {
        dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
        dependency = null;
    }
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        MyHub.Send();
    }
}
```

}

No exception is raised. On thing I noticed is when

using (command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  [NotificationId],[UserId],[IsSeen],[Message],[CreatedDate],[ActionID] FROM [dbo].[tblNotification]", connection))

is there, during execution of GetNotificationCount() function, debugger does not go to dependency_OnChange event. But when

using (command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  COUNT([NotificationId]) as NotificationCount FROM [dbo].[tblNotification]", connection))

is there, debugger moves to and from between GetNotificationCount() and dependency_OnChange().

So when I add new record in sql table, dependency_OnChange() does not gets fired.

Comment: That query can't be used with query notifications. Query notifications work [only with specific SELECT queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122(v=sql.105)#supported-select-statements) . The only aggregates allowed are `COUNT_BIG` or `SUM` with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: thanks for the info and link.... it worked